# Are you allowed to save to the managed object context (Core Data) while typing in a TextEditor (Text Field Input)?

Tags: core-data, swiftui, combine, observedobject

The question is best explained in an example:

```
struct MyEditor: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjectContext
    
    @ObservedObject var song: Song
    
    var body: some View {
        TextEditor(text: $song.lyrics)
            .navigationTitle(song.title)
            .onChange(of: song.lyrics) { newValue in
                try? managedObjectContext.save()
            }
    }
}
```

It feels wrong to spam `save` but I want to make sure the data is stored. Is this allowed and a correct way to do it?

Another way I can think of is to create a publisher that smoothens the signal to save. If this is the correct way to do it. Can I retrieve the publisher from the ObservedObject or do I have to create a different `@State` property for that and use `onChange` to pass the values.

```
struct MyEditor: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjectContext
    
    @ObservedObject var song: Song
    
    @State private var lyricsPublisher = PassthroughSubject<String, Never>()
    
    var body: some View {
        TextEditor(text: $song.lyrics)
            .navigationTitle(song.title)
            .onChange(of: song.lyrics) { newValue in
                lyricsPublisher.send(newValue)
            }
            .onReceive(lyricsPublisher
                .debounce(for: 0.5, scheduler: RunLoop.main)
                .removeDuplicates()
            ) { value in
                try? managedObjectContext.save()
            }
    }
}
```

This is what Song looks like as a `ManagedObject`.

```
@objc(Song)
class Song: NSManagedObject, Identifiable {
    @nonobjc class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Song> {
        return NSFetchRequest<Scribble>(entityName: "Song")
    }

    @NSManaged public var id: UUID
    @NSManaged public var title: String
    @NSManaged public var lyrics: String
}
```

Comment: The standard way is create a child context and fetch the object by ID, use a sheet with save and cancel buttons. If they tap cancel then discard the child context if they tap save then save the child context if there are any errors like validation then alert the user to fix the problems, once it passes hide the sheet and save the main context. Use an @State EditorConfig struct to hold the child context and the object.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that the child context remains in memory. Meaning if the user closes the application or it crashes it lost all its work. Also I don't see this approach in the Notes app where you need to save your changes. You just write the edits for the notes and you can expect the app to store it.

Comment: No the child context can be deinit when the sheet closes, either by setting it to nil on the struct or setting the entire state struct to nil. Take a look at Apples CoreDataBooks sample (it's not SwiftUI though) https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/CoreDataBooks/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008405 But sure it's fine to save on a timer like Notes does. For form data where fields are validated I prefer the former though.

Comment: I understand. I am going to play with it, thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to use publisher of managed object (`ObservedObject`) directly, like

```
var body: some View {
    TextEditor(text: $song.lyrics)
        .navigationTitle(song.title)
        .onReceive(song.publisher(for: \.lyrics)      // << here !!
            .debounce(for: 0.5, scheduler: DispatchQueue.main)
            .removeDuplicates()
        ) { value in
            try? managedObjectContext.save()
        }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure? I get the following runtime error: "Value of type 'Song' has no dynamic member '$lyrics' using key path from root type 'Song'".  I will extend my question with how the Song looks like as a ManagedObject.

Comment: This was the correct way I believe: `.onReceive(song.publisher(for: \.content)`

Comment: Yes, you're right - I typed right here and did not verify.

Answer (score 1):

Credits to @lorem_ipsum and @Asperi.

I combined their solutions into one.

```
struct MyEditor: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjectContext
    
    @ObservedObject var song: Song
    
    var body: some View {
        TextEditor(text: $song.lyrics)
            .navigationTitle(song.name)
            .onReceive(song.publisher(for: \.lyrics)
                .debounce(for: 0.5, scheduler: RunLoop.main)
                .removeDuplicates()
            ) { _ in
                if song.hasChanges {
                    try? managedObjectContext.save()
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you thought about if your save fails?